# How do I unit test a filter function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I'm building a live music gig listing app in React Native with expo.

An array of gig objects is fetched from firebase, with the following shape:

```
gigs:
[
  {
    dateAndTime:{seconds:2345234748},
    gigName: 'gigAtVenue',
    ...
  },
  {...}
]
```

In my component `listByDay.txs`, I've written some code to filter through this array of gig objects, and return only the current day's gigs:

```
 const gigsToday = gigs.filter((gig) => { 
    const formattedDate = format(new Date(currentDateMs), 'do MMMM Y')
    const formattedGigDate = format(new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds*1000) ,'do MMMM Y')
    return formattedGigDate === formattedDate
  })
```

I've written the following test, but it seems very clunky to be re-writing the filter function for my test - is there a way I can "extract" the filter from it's component `listByDay.tsx`? What's the best library to use for a test like this?

```
    test('should filter gigs by date', () => {
      // create an array of gigs
      const gigs = [
        { dateAndTime: { seconds: 1609459200 } }, // 1 September 2021
        { dateAndTime: { seconds: 1609545600 } }, // 2 September 2021
        { dateAndTime: { seconds: 1609632000 } }, // 3 September 2021
      ]
  
      // create a new date object with the current date
      const currentDate = new Date(2021, 8, 1) // 1 September 2021
  
      // pass the gigs and currentDate to the filter function
      const gigsToday = gigs.filter((gig) => { 
        const formattedDate = format(currentDate, 'do MMMM Y')
        const formattedGigDate = format(new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds*1000) ,'do MMMM Y')
        return formattedGigDate === formattedDate
      })
  
      // check that the filter function returned the correct gigs
      expect(gigsToday).toBe([{ dateAndTime: { seconds: 1609459200 } }])
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a standalone callback function to be used by the first parameter of `Array.filter`.

Remove the callback function from the react component body, then you can export the function to be unit tested it by itself.

```
const gigs = [{
  dateAndTime: {
    seconds: 2345234748
  },
  gigName: 'gigAtVenue',
}]

export const filterByToday = (gig) => {
  const formattedDate = format(new Date(currentDateMs), 'do MMMM Y')
  const formattedGigDate = format(new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds * 1000), 'do MMMM Y')
  return formattedGigDate === formattedDate
}


const ListByDay = ({ gigs }) => {
  const gigsToday = gigs.filter(filterByToday)

  return (
    // some JSX
  )
}
```

[image: Edit eager-williams-80op2g]

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that and found that I can't export functions that are within a react functional component.

Comment: It does not need to be inside the body of the react function component. Just move `filterByToday` outside the component, inside the same file